# How to set equal amount of spacing from the font awesome icon or text using css

Tags: html, css

[image]

Actually i don't know what this is called so i rather posted the image, i was going through a website and i saw this that the icon was aligned on the left side and the text was on the right side now i liked the thing that how much ever the big text is it is not going below the icon its breaking the line in its linear position. How to achieve this. Also what is this called?

Comment: This site is for question  programming related

Comment: I would guess they're absolutely positioning the icon to the left and applying a left padding to the text, however there are many ways to accomplish this, there's no way to tell for sure just from an image.

Comment: It's probably something like this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhf472ot/) that you're looking for. It uses a Pseudo element and absolute positioning to position the icon the left of the text. You can find the content links here [astronautweb](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

Comment: Thanks, @Simon that's exactly what i wanted can u answer this as comment so that i can give it a green mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ( [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhf472ot/) ) is a combination of position: absolute and using font awesome icons in a CSS pseudo element:

```
.example {
width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

.example::before {
content: "\f041";
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: inherit;
color: #000;
font-size: 32px;
padding-right: 0.5em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -30px;
}
```

All the HTML you need is a single element (a div in this example):

```
<div class="example">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem commodi obcaecati, explicabo culpa iusto quae magni atque officiis nam qui sit inventore suscipit expedita facilis eum quas voluptatum laborum impedit.
</div>
```

This code is based on [astronautweb.co](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) and their list of CSS values for Font Awesome icons.